# Redirect to new page after AJAX post request using express

Tags: javascript, ajax, express

I need to make a button that on click redirects me to a new page (localhost:1337/LEDon) and logs some data to the console. However, I can't get the button click to load a new page.

Here's my code -

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/view.html');
});

app.post('/LEDon', function(req, res) {
  console.log('LEDon button pressed!');
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/success.html');
});

app.listen(1337);
```

**clientside.js**

```
$('#ledon-button').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/LEDon'
    });
});
```

**view.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <button id='ledon-button'>LED on</button>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='clientside.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**success.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Success page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    LEDon button pressed!!
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A few ways of doing this, but if the code is as simple as you have it here you can just do a `success:` function for your ajax call and set window.location to the URL you'd like

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:1337/LEDon',
        success:function(data, code, jqXHR) {
            window.location.pathname = "success.html"
        }
});
```

and your node:

```
app.post('/LEDon', function(req, res) {
  console.log('LEDon button pressed!');
  res.status(200)
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/success.html');
  res.end()
});
```

Is one way of doing it, provided this is the only functionality you want for it. Otherwise you can send a 3XX HTML Status code and the browser will deal with it for you, I believe

Comment: So, I did that and now it logs 'LEDon button pressed' but it doesn't render the `success.html` page. It also gives me this error - `jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:1337/LEDon net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`. Also, could you please add an example of doing it by sending the 3XX HTML status code because I definitely need additional functionality.

Comment: Oops sorry, I misread your question, I thought you were trying to pull that page. Just change window.location.pathname to success.html.

Comment: Also, why are you using sendFile to deliver your HTML content? I'd use res.render(file.html). sendFile is for when you're explicitly telling the client to get that file.

Comment: I replaced it with `window.location.pathname = "../success.html"` as I put `clientside.js` in the `assets` folder. It's still the same issue.

Comment: Also, I don't exactly know how to use `res.render()` so I'm looking that up.

Comment: You are also missing res.end(). I'd send a status code with res.status(200) and then res.end() so that it finishes the request.

Comment: I had to write `app.get('/success.html', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/success.html');
});` and `app.post('/LEDon', function(req, res) {
  console.log('LEDon button pressed!');
  res.status(200);
  res.end();
});` for it to work. But it does now.

Comment: Ah I thought you'd already written the success.html route! Glad you got it figured out.